# Is it possible for P2P software to find a partner by public key without using IP address?

Tags: p2p, public-key-encryption

Some P2P software (e.g. Tox, Briar, etc.) uses public key encryption instead of IP addresses. to exchange messages with other people. Is this possible and how?

Comment: PK cannot replace IP addresses, and in fact all modern Internet PKI absolutely requires IP. Those softwares almost certianly use abstraction and intermediaries to provide obfuscation and to prevent peers from seeing each others IPs but all messages are sent by IP one way or another, so the trick is just in how you enable the messaging but without peers exchanging actual IPs (and thus being able to identify other parties to the communication).

Comment: @FrankThomas While PKI is most commonly used over the Internet it does not require IP addresses.  PGP would be a good example of PKI which can used over an IP network but does not require the Internet to work.

Comment: Fair enough. I was attempting to argue for the reliance of modern PKI on IP, not necessarily on the specific internetwork known as The Internet, but I suppose any compliant level 3/4 internetwork  protocol could work as minimal standards for internetwork PKI. been a long time since I saw anyone talking about IPX/SPX or SNA or decnet, but I;m sure they are still relevant to someone. in particular I mentioned the PKI as "modern internet PKI" specifically to exclude bygone layer 3/4 protocols from the conversation, but perhaps that was a bigger error than acknowledging them.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing to barely related technologies.

Internet connected computers require IP addresses to communicate with each other.   This is a fundamental requirement.   In order for P2P software to communicate over the Internet **it will be using IP addresses of the P2P participants.**

Public Key Infrastructure is something entirely different.  It is the idea that one can have 2 keys - a public and private key.   Messages encrypted with the private key can only be decrypted with the public key and vice versa.    **PK systems allow for message encryption and decryption regardless of how the message is delivered** - so for example if the message was transported on a USB key it would still be secure.

It does, of-course, make sense for PK messages to be distributed using the Internet so this is the most common use case - and I expect where the first part of the confusion is coming in.

Looking at TOX for example  - have a read of https://tox.chat/faq.html - I've highlighted a key bit below:

**Tox makes no attempt to cloak your IP address** when communicating with friends, as the whole point of a peer-to-peer network is to connect you directly to your friends. A workaround does exist in the form of tunneling your Tox connections through Tor. However, a non-friend user cannot easily discover your IP address using only a Tox ID; you reveal your IP address to someone only when you add them to your contacts list.

(If you are not using TOR, It seems Tox uses bootstrap nodes to help friends find each others IP addresses.   Tor, of-course serves an equivalent purpose)

Looking at Briar - It appears to be able to communicate using means other then the Internet (ie Bluetooth).    That said, it also uses Tor to map IP addresses to users.  It also talks about WIFI for local connections - this is when multiple devices are on the same LAN and can send broadcast messages to find each others IP addresses.  (Ever installed a new network printer and had  it show up on computers? ).

TOR of-course, is like a VPN overlayed over a number of internet connections whose purpose is to obfusicate communications between nodes.  TOR still uses IP addresses - although it can disassociate your IP address from the IP addresses you are communicating with.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that Tox ID doesn't contain IP but consists of public key and other things that go along with it, so I'm asking why it can communicate with the other people.

Comment: Per my 2nd and 7th  paragraph - Tox requires a mechanism which maps the ID with an IP address that  packets can be delivered to (ie an IP address).    It can use TOR or DHT to do this mapping.    This functionality will be built into the Tox client.   (If you think about it, no common messaging system has a userid that contains an IP address, resolving/accessing the IP address handled by the protocol )

Comment: Also see "What is the purpose of boostrap nodes" at https://wiki.tox.chat/users/nodes to explain the process.

Answer (score 0):

It is not impossible.  For example, bitcoin users do not need to know each other's IP addresses.

You could, for example, fire up an NNTP server, and invite people to post encrypted messages to a news group ... everybody hosting the newsgroup would download all of the messages, but they would only be able to read those messages that were de-crypt-able by them.

That way, the bad guys cannot see who is reading what messages, without finding out what keys each user holds.